# How can I custom spring validation message at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-validator, spring-validation

```java
@Data
public class TestData {

    private Integer x;
    private Integer y;

    @AssertTrue
    public boolean isValid() {
        String message;

        if (x > y) {
            message = "message1..."; // here
            return false;
        }
        else if (x < y) {
            message = "messsage2..." // and here
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

I know it's possible to set the message in the `@AssertTrue` annotation (`@AssertTrue(message = "default messsage")`), but I wonder if there is a way to dynamically set the message at runtime.